# Sort alphanumeric array, consecutive numbers should reside at last

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I want to sort an alphanumeric, but numbers should come at end instead of beginning. for instance

```
let array = ["1", "a", "b", "z", "3", "!"]
let sortedArray = array.sort { (firstObject, secondObject) -> Bool in
    firstObject < secondObject
}
```

**output:**

> ["!", "1", "3", "a", "b", "z"]

**Required output:**

> ["a", "b", "z", "1", "3", "!"]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so? Why don't you just try to do exactly that? obviously `firstObject < secondObject` is wrong for your use case. You probably have to compare the charcodes a little bit more sophisticated. Have you tried that?

Comment: what is rule of sort here? why "!" is the end of sorted array?

Comment: If your desired result differs from common ordering conventions, this task should have custom solution (as exclamation char is in the end, as well as numbers behind alphabetic chars).

Comment: `"!"` is not alphanumeric. If then array can contain arbitrary characters, where should `ä € ~ π   β ☼ ∬ ` be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works for your case :

**The expected result is :**

- letters first ;
- then numbers ;
- then others ;

Here's a way to do it.

```
// Works with both arrays
var array = ["1", "b", "a", "z", "3", "!"]
//var array = ["1", "b", "A", "Z", "3", "!"]

func isLetter(char: String) -> Bool {
    return ("a"..."z").contains(char) || ("A"..."Z").contains(char)
}

func isNumber(char: String) -> Bool {
    return Int(char) != nil
}

let letters = array.filter(isLetter).sort{$0.lowercaseString < $1.lowercaseString}
let numbers = array.filter(isNumber).sort{Int($0) < Int($1)}
let others = Array(Set(array).subtract(letters).subtract(numbers)).sort{$0 < $1}

let sortedArray = letters + numbers + others
```

The first array would be

```
["a", "b", "z", "1", "3", "!"]
```

The second would be

```
["A", "b", "Z", "1", "3", "!"]
```

It does what you want. Include unit tests and wrap that inside a method and you're good to go. Buuuut, it's not "clean" at all.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you want to receive "*numbers should come at end instead of beginning*", without watching your example with unexpected "!" sorting. Then you can do this:

```
let array = ["1", "a", "b", "z", "3", "!"]
let sortedArray = array.sort { (firstObject, secondObject) -> Bool in
    let firstIsNumber = firstObject.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet())?.count > 0
    let secondIsNumber = secondObject.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet())?.count > 0
    if firstIsNumber != secondIsNumber {return secondIsNumber}
    return firstObject < secondObject
}
print(sortedArray)
//["!", "a", "b", "z", "1", "3"]
```